# How to update every subdocument conditionally in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```
{
  _id: ObjectId(),
  animals: [
    { type: "dog", IQ: 100  }, 
    { type: "cat", IQ: 110  }, 
    { type: "bear", IQ: 120  }, 
    ...
  ]
}
```

How to write an updateOne statement to update the IQ field of every subdocument of the `animals`'s field conditionally based on the `type` field of the subdocument?

For example,

if `type === "dog"`, then update IQ  to 200, but if `type === "cat"`, then update IQ  to 300, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pipelined form of update like this:

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "animals": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$animals",
          "in": {
            "$switch": {
              "branches": [
                {
                  "case": {
                    "$eq": [
                      "$$this.type",
                      "dog"
                    ]
                  },
                  "then": {
                    $mergeObjects: [
                      "$$this",
                      {
                        IQ: 200
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                },
                {
                  "case": {
                    "$eq": [
                      "$$this.type",
                      "cat"
                    ]
                  },
                  "then": {
                    $mergeObjects: [
                      "$$this",
                      {
                        IQ: 300
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ],
              default: "$$this"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Loop over the array using `$map`, and use `$switch` to conditionally set the IQ. [Playground link.](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mWajCQFpM0s)

Comment: What if the subdocument has many many fields, and I do not know beforehand what the values of those other fields are, how would I structure the `                  "then": {
                    type: "cat",
                    IQ: 300
                  }` part?

Comment: That's working beautifully. thx. Final question. Is this update query efficient if there are indexes on the animal field?

Comment: The index will be used for filtering the documents, so if you use animals key in filtering, then the index will be used, otherwise it won't be used.

Comment: no meant, the process of updating the index after the update query.

Comment: yeah that will be optimal